# How to access auth instance in fetch()?

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) module and I am refactoring my code, that is why I want to access the `auth` instance within `fetch()` method I use in **pages/index.vue** component page.

I tried:

- `console.log(this.$auth)`
- `console.log($auth)`

I get undefined.

Note that elsewhere, I access the `auth` instance without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access through vuex: store.state.auth

```
  async fetch ({ store }) {
    store.$auth.$state
  }
```

Comment: I just  tried, it says 'Can not read state of undefined'. Thank you

Comment: Do you have vuex?
store souldn't be undefined

Comment: Of course I do because there is a lot of data in my `store/` folder.

Comment: I think you have to check why your store is undefined. You should have access to the store in fetch method

Comment: I tried `store.$state.$auth` and that works. if you updated your answer, I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: @Begueradj thats not right, it should be store.state, not $state

Comment: That is what Manu suggested in the beginning. It did not work. The `$` version is the only one that works. @Aldarund

Comment: @Begueradj I don't see a way that store.$state should work, there no such thing as store.$state at all

Comment: I just checked again why it works on my browser while you say this is wrong, and I found I did a typo in the comment: `store.$auth.$state` thank you very much @Aldarund